# "This is the first time my sister has given me affirmative" is this the correct expression?

Tags: grammaticality, syntax

> This is the first time my sister has given me affirmative.

Is the above sentence correct? I am a little confused that **given me** is not a correct word.

With the given sentence I mean to say that this is the first time my sister has given me approval or has approved me. Have I used the correct expression here? Or could I have used a better expression?

Answer (score 4):

> "This is the first time my sister has given me her approval."

Would be better, as **approval** is an abstract noun, and **affirmative** is usually used as an adjective, for example *affirmative action* - you would use it in the same way you would use the word 'positive'.

Comment: Although you could say "an affirmative"; [see definition 2 for the noun sense.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affirmative)

Answer (score 2):

If there is a *tangible* object being passed from one person to another, then we can say it either way:

> On the first day of Christmas my true love **gave to me** a partridge in
>   a pear tree.
>
> On the first day of Christmas my true love **gave** a partridge in
>   a pear tree **to me**.
>
> On the first day of Christmas my true love **gave me** a partridge in a
>   pear tree.

But if what is being given is *intangible*  then we tend not to use **to**.

> She **gave me** her approval.
>
> I do not like that model car. I would not **give it** a second look.
>
> **Give me** some time. I need more time!
>
> She **gave me** quite a surprise, showing up unannounced like that.
>
> The frayed wire **gave him** a shock.
>
> Your essay is very good.  I will **give it** a B+.
>
> The risk of running out of gas in the middle of the desert **gave me** pause.

Comment: "[somebody] gave to me [something]" isn't a very common construct, indeed regardless of whether it is *technically* wrong it *sounds* wrong to me. (Song lyrics are a special case though, and I do like that song.) "Gave me [something]" or "gave [something] to me" are much more common ways of putting it.

Comment: `give to {pronoun} {something}` is relatively rare in contemporary speech. But you will see it in written works.  *The company gives to all employees when they retire a graphite putter with a platinum head.*

Answer (score -3):

I think you should use past tense of "give" here. Because at the time you were talking about the "affirmative", it had happened and didn't last.

> This is the first time my sister **gave** me affirmative.